# Is there a way to increase tracking speed beyond mac's fastest point?

Tags: macos, macbook-pro, big-sur

I have 3x 27" screens and it takes quite a bit to get the mouse to go from one to the other.

I have the tracking speed set to go as fast as it can, is there a way to make it even faster?

I have come from a PC where it is a lot more sensitive so this feels still quite slow.

This is what my machine is
[image]

ta

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You probably don't want the base speed any higher, as it makes precision harder to control.

Instead, try increasing the acceleration. This will allow precision at low speeds but a 'fast whip' at high speeds.

You can do this manually in Terminal. The default value should be 2 [but isn't always]. Check the current value using
`defaults read .GlobalPreferences com.apple.mouse.scaling`
then adjust with
`defaults write .GlobalPreferences com.apple.mouse.scaling 2`
You'll need to log out to use the new value.

Alternatively, there's a 3rd party Control Panel which can adjust it on the fly- [Mouse Acceleration Preference Pane](http://triq.net/mac/mouse-acceleration) (donationware) . [I've not tried this myself.]

Source: [OSXDaily - Mouse Acceleration on a Mac – What it is and How to Adjust or Disable it](https://osxdaily.com/2010/08/25/mouse-acceleration/)

Comment: thank you @Tetsujin, that sounds like a great idea.  I will give that ago :)